# D3: how to show lone point in a line chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have some data where few data points may not be available (`=== null`). To show that data is missing, I am using the `line.defined` function of d3 (as show [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3035090)) . The problem is that sometimes I have a point which does not have a value on either side and hence does not get displayed on the graph.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nxrdybdx/3/

As you can see, data is missing for April 27 and 29 and so the line is disjoint. Great. The data value on April 28 is non-null but does not get displayed.

I want that a dot gets displayed for April 28. What am I missing? Do I need to add a dot (svg circle) corresponding to each point so that when alone, each point gets displayed on its own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only drawing the lines with

```
svg.append("path") // Add the valueline path.
.attr("d", valueline(data));
```

If you want to draw the circle like the example you provided, you need to add

```
svg.selectAll(".dot")
    .data(data.filter(function(d) { return d; }))
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "dot")
    .attr("cx", line.x())
    .attr("cy", line.y())
    .attr("r", 3.5);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/tgx48xzn/

PS :

if you want to hide the null value points, you can had

```
.filter(function(d) { return d.close !== null })
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/tgx48xzn/1/

PS 2

if you want to show only the isolated points, filter like that

```
.filter(function(d, i) {
    return d.close !== null && i > 1
    && data[i - 1].close === null
    && data[i + 1].close === null;

})
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/tgx48xzn/3/

Comment: Actually, I don't want any circles. I just want that the lone point gets displayed too. Is adding circles the only way?

Comment: the solution in PS2 would work for me. Although, I still wonder if adding the svg circles the only way to show the isolated points. The reason I am looking for something else is that I am going to use it in a phone app. When the user rotates the screen, all these svg circles would need to be transformed too (along with few other svg element that I am already transforming). It wouldn't be difficult but I wanted to minimize the processing.

Comment: A circle is the best way to display it in my opinion as a line of length 0 is not possible